# Where are these variables defined? - bytecomp Warnings

Tags: variables, byte-compilation, warning

Lately I'm getting warnings when compiling the `.emacs`

```
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘url-http-extra-headers’
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘oauth--token-data’
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘url-callback-function’
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘url-callback-arguments’
```

I don't know were this variables are defined, and thus cannot constraint the errors.

**Q1:** Does anyone know were the problem is?

**Q2:** How to solve the problem?

Comment: You're probably setting variables that aren't defined when their assignments are evaluated. You can look for where variables are defined with `M-.`, but that will probably fail if you haven't loaded the file that defines the offending variable yet.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Agreed, just one minor correction: Replace "You're" with "You or one of the packages getting loaded during byte-compilation are".

Comment: If you set `after-init-time` to `t` at the top of your .emacs does the warning get a filename? (refer [Re: "reference to free variable" only during initialization](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2017-01/msg00556.html), continued [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2017-02/msg00625.html))

Answer (score 5):

See the [answer by Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37040/15748) for a general description of compiler warnings pertaining to free variables.

In your particular case, however, the culprit is the package [`oauth2.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/elpa.git/tree/packages/oauth2/oauth2.el), which for some reason is getting loaded during the byte-compilation of your `user-init-file` (perhaps you are a `use-package` user?).

In this case adding `(defvar foo)` to your `user-init-file` will not make the warnings go away. Instead, you could try assigning a value to the corresponding variables before the `oauth2` package is loaded in your `user-init-file`, e.g.

```el
    (eval-when-compile
      (defvar oauth--token-data ())
```

**Update**

I removed my suggestion to raise the issue with the `oauth2` package from my answer, as byte-compiling the package on its own does not raise the warnings mentioned. In my case, at least, the warnings only appear because of the way `use-package` loads files before byte-compiling user settings, and I'm not entirely sure why, though it's related to the fact that all variables mentioned are void, i.e. they have been defined with `defvar` but not assigned a value.

Comment: It's probably due to oauth2.el's use of `defadvice`, it has strange interactions with compilation. The nadvice interface is much better about this.

Comment: An easy way to avoid the warnings is to defer loading the problematic package:
`(use-package oauth2 :defer t)`

Answer (score 2):

Those are only warnings, which means that the rest of your code that loads libraries or whatever should still do that.

In that case, you can use `C-h v` to find out where each such variable is defined. If such a variable is defined in a library that you load, then you need tell the byte compiler not to worry about that variable, i.e., that it will be properly defined before it is actually used.

To do that you put a vacuous `defvar` for that variable in your init file. For example, if the variable is `foo` then you put this in your init file, before it otherwise refers to `foo`:

```
(defvar foo)
```

Note that there is no initial value provided for `foo` by this `defvar`.

See the Elisp manual, nodes [Defining Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html) and [Compiler Errors](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Compiler-Errors.html).

Comment: It didn't solve to me.